# It is required synchronized keyword for non void method?

Tags: java

If method have return type and it is access by two or more thread then it is required to use synchronized block or keyword with this method?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: It is not required, but it may be needed depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

No. If that method does changes any of the field of the object that its operating upon (i.e. changing the state of object) and same object is shared amongst two thread then you might need it.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use synchronized when you are reading fields which can be changed in another thread, or writing fields which might be read in another thread.  There is no specific rule of when you must, or must not use `synchronized` or the language would be able to do this for you.  It is up to you to decide based on you use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required. For example, if your class does not offer methods which modify instances of this class (then the class is said to be immutable) you don't need to synchronize.

However, as soon as at least one thread can write to some member variable, and there exist other threads which can read from or write to this variable at the same time, you need to synchronize the access to this variable, either by using the `synchronized` keyword or by manipulating locks explicitly. In some cases, you might also use atomic operation (`AtomicInteger`, for example).